# Modifying a multidimensional Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array [1,2], [3,4], [5,6].  How can I modify the values in the second column (eg. add 1 to each value, so the result would be ([1,3], [3,5], [5,7])?

Comment: `arr[:,1] += 1`

Answer (score 2):

Psidom's comment above worked thanks.

arr[:,1] += 1